# C++ Infinite Loop repeating

Tags: c++

```
int departmentNo;
bool depNumIncorrect = false;
do
{
    depNumIncorrect = false;
    cout << "Please enter your department number... ( 1 / 2 / 3 )" << endl;
    cin >> departmentNo;
    if (departmentNo < 1 || departmentNo > 3)
    {
        cout << "Invalid Entry." << endl;
        depNumIncorrect = true;
    }
} while (depNumIncorrect == true);
```

Whenever I input a correct input (1/2/3), the code works fine and continues without looping. Whenever I input an incorrect integer, the code loops as it is supposed to. But when I input a character or a string, it puts the code into an infinite loop. The "Please enter your department number... ( 1 / 2 / 3 )" is repeatedly output to the console.

How could I go about changing this so that it doesn't start an infinite loop when a character or string is input, but rather loops as it is supposed to and allows me to input again?

Comment: You have to clear error flag of `std::cin`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to C++, how would I do that?

Comment: Can we assume `departmentNo` is an `int` of sorts? A [mcve] (including `main()`) and a concrete example of input that puts your code into an infinite loop, and a more accurate title would make this a good question imo

Answer (score 0):

deparmentNo is (I assume) an Int and you have a problem of conversion. As mentioned by others you should clear error flag of std::cin. Moreover you probably should not cin directly into an int but rather to a string , and then attempting conversion to int. The result of conversion attempt (successful or not) would be an additional criteria to check for valid entry